# Matlab's backslash operator understanding

Tags: matlab

Can sombody please show me how the forward slash operator applies to this?

Say we have

```
P = [3, 3, 1] 
and A = zeros(3,3); 

A(1,:) = [30, 15, 1];
A(2,:) = [10, 20, 1]; 
A(3,:) = [1,  1,  1];
```

what would:

`x = A\P` look like?

Comment: First of all, that's the backslash operator [(`mldivide`)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html). Second, try it!

Comment: I guess i'm confused because the documentation says that A and P would have to have the same number of rows? When I assign P = [3,3,1] should I be thinking of that as a single column with three rows, instead of a single row with three columns? So in other words, mldivide(A,P) would solve Ax = P for x, for each row?

Comment: That is correct. I'm guessing you want `P.'`. But I don't have any context on this problem.

Comment: I had to look up what P.' does, so basically the transpose of P which would make P.' a matrix with 1 column 3 rows, instead of 3 column and 1 row? Sorry if I'm starting to get it mixed up.

Comment: You were right, I want P.' which now makes the mldivide operator much more clear. Thanks a lot, wish I could accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `P.'`, the transpose.